# AWS Ingress Controller seems to be ignoring host name rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy a frontend application to Amazon EKS. The concept is that there will be two deployments as well as two services (`frontend-service` and `stg-frontend-service`), one for production and one for staging.

On top of that, there will be an ingress ALB which will redirect traffic based on the hostname. i.e. if the hostname is `www.project.io`, traffic will be routed to `frontend-service` and if the hostname is `stg-project.io`, traffic will be routed to `stg-frontend-service`.

Here are my deployment and ingress configs

`stg-frontend-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stg-frontend-deployment
  namespace: project
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stg-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stg-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: stg-frontend
          image: STAGING_IMAGE
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: project-ecr

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stg-frontend-service
  namespace: project
spec:
  selector:
    app: stg-frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

`stg-prod-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  namespace: project
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: PRODUCTION_IMAGE
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: project-ecr

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: project
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

`ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: project-ingress
  namespace: project
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.project.io
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: stg.project.io
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: stg-frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Later, I have used Route 53 to route traffic from both domain to the ALB.

```
+----------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  Record Name   | Type | Routing |               Value/Route traffic to                |
+----------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| www.project.io | A    | Simple  | dualstack.k8s-********.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com. |
| stg.project.io | A    | Simple  | dualstack.k8s-********.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com. |
+----------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is, ALB ingress is always routing traffic to the first spec rules. In the config above, the first rule is host `www.project.io` which refers to `frontend-service`. Whenever I am trying to access `www.project.io` or `stg.project.io`, it's showing me a response from `frontend-service`.

Later, I have switched the rules and put staging rules first, and then it was showing staging service on both domains.

I even created a dummy record like `junk.project.io` and pointed to the load balancer, it still worked and showed me the same response, even though `junk.project.io` is not included in my ingress config.

It seems to me that Ingress Config is totally ignoring what the host name is and always returning response from the first rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host and http values are defined as separate items in the list, try removing the `-` (hyphen) in front of the http node:

```yaml
  - host: www.project.io
    http: # I removed the hyphen here
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: stg.project.io
    http: # I removed the hyphen here
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: stg-frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: It worked. I can't believe I have spent an entire day just for this hyphen -_-

Comment: @HowardScott Happened to me too bro! Took me lots of head scratching and water breaks (4 hours) :D We should prolly build a validator for this stuff haha

Answer (score 0):

```
ways to check that issue

1. check the external dns status

> kubectl logs 'external dns pod name' -n 'namespace'
    
2. check if the ALB ingress controller has any error
> kubectl logs 'aws load balancer controller pod name' -n 'namespace'`



the error I encoutered is that the alb name is in uppercase, everything else can work just the "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname" is not triggered in Ingress.yaml
```